# Pyppeteer AsyncHTMLSession never returns Arender when ran on Ubuntu + Django + Celery in async

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-requests-html, pyppeteer

I have a scraping function that takes a URL and uses a AsyncHTMLSession to scrape generative content off websites - the sites I'm accessing are JS heavy so this is necessary.

I've also added asynchronous debugging lines to the function that log to the database as this made checking the status of the code far easier.

```py
import pyppeteer
import requests
from celery import shared_task
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

async def load_page_helper(url: str):   # THE ASYNC PAGE LOADER

    set_state_async.delay("load_page_helper 1")

    session = AsyncHTMLSession()

    set_state_async.delay("load_page_helper 2")

    browser = await pyppeteer.launch({
        'ignoreHTTPSErrors': True,
        'headless': True,
        'handleSIGINT': False,
        'handleSIGTERM': False,
        'handleSIGHUP': False
    })

    set_state_async.delay("load_page_helper 3")

    session._browser = browser

    resp = await session.get(url)

    set_state_async.delay("load_page_helper 4 - should time out by 100 seconds")

    await resp.html.arender(timeout=100)

    set_state_async.delay("load_page_helper 5")

    await session.close()

    set_state_async.delay("load_page_helper 6")

    return resp

@shared_task
def set_state_async(state):    # FUNCTION FOR ASYNC DB LOGGING
    db.set_state(state)

@shared_task
def scrape_data_async():    # AN EXAMPLE OF HOW THE FUNCTION IS CALLED ASYNC (1/2)
    base_link = "example.com"

scrape_data_async.delay()   # AN EXAMPLE OF HOW THE FUNCTION IS CALLED ASYNC (2/2)
```

I ran this code 3 times with a URL that is pingable using traceroute from my Ubuntu server. The resulting output to the DB is shown below:

```
# TEST 1
2023-04-14 21:44:24.031933 - load_page_helper 1
2023-04-14 21:44:24.570362 - load_page_helper 3
2023-04-14 21:44:25.799122 - load_page_helper 4 - should time out by 100 seconds

# TEST 2
2023-04-14 21:46:37.121347 - load_page_helper 2
2023-04-14 21:46:37.838199 - load_page_helper 3
2023-04-14 21:46:39.214201 - load_page_helper 4 - should time out by 100 seconds

# TEST 3
2023-04-14 21:49:03.778309 - load_page_helper 2
2023-04-14 21:49:04.622361 - load_page_helper 3
2023-04-14 21:49:06.194292 - load_page_helper 4 - should time out by 100 seconds
```

As you can see, sometimes some of the messages aren't printed out consistently, but it always hangs at the same place, `load_page_helper 4` which is next to the render call.

---

**What I know:**

- Chromium is installed, as is all of its dependencies.
- Celery is configured correctly, as otherwise the DB wouldn't get logged to. Regardless, other celery tasks run fine on my server.
- The website is accessible from the server as far as I can tell, using traceroute to verify.
- The website accepts scraping - I'm attempting to access the same site on Ubuntu as I have successfully done on Windows.
- The browser successful launches - when ran synchronously, `2023-04-14 17:48:42,587 INFO pyppeteer.launcher Browser listening on: ws://127.0.0.1:34137/devtools/browser/80d7f76c-aee8-4b15-9fa7-42298ef7eb2c` is output to the log, before the request crashes (see below). Regardless, it still takes >20 seconds to crash, which has been long enough for render to work previously.

I also don't think I can run it synchronously as CloudFlare detects a timeout and slaps the request with a 502, which also appears to stop the thread from executing.

I've looked all around and I can't find a solution as to why this isn't running. **It works on Windows when running sychronously**, so this leads me to believe that it might be struggling to run within an async call?